# spring boot fancy filtering for rest based on fields values

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring boot application that exposes some endpoints. What I want to achieve is to provide a fancy filtering mechanism based on fields values. Let's say I have two domain models: Article and Author, where an article can be written by a list of Authors.

```
@Entity
public class Article{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String body;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Author> authors;

    //Getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Author{

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    //Getter and setters
}
```

For now, I can access all my articles using the endpoint: ***localhost:8080/api/articles***, and with the new filtering system that I want to integrate, I would like to have something like: ***localhost:8080/api/articles?title=myTitle*** to retrieve articles by title, or ***localhost:8080/api/articles?title=mytitle&author.firstname=Jhon*** to retrieve articles by titles and author's firstname.

I looked into JPA specifications and succeeded to make a first filtering on the direct fields of my models, but I can't make it work for nested fields, or enumeration types. Any library or other solution to achieve such need?

Comment: QueryDsl or write custom repository and use Criteria

Comment: @pvpkiran That's what I did following baeldung articles: http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-querydsl But it doesn't handle the nested objects, or couldn't find how. :/

Comment: of course it works with nested fields.

Answer (score 0):

QueryDsl would be an option in these kinda scenario. And of course it is possible to query for nested fields using QueryDsl.
For the case you need, this would be the predicate

```
BooleanExpression predicate = QArticle.title.eq(mytitle);
predicate.and(QArticle.authors.any().firstname.eq(John))
ArticleRepository.findAll(predicate);
```

Comment: That's a very intersting lead, but what's the QArticle class?! Can you give more details, since I followed Baeldung article, he deals directly with the domain models, and the domain models predicate

Comment: When you compile your project, JPAAnnotationProcessor(which you have in maven) generates a new class (with prefix Q)for each entity class. compile your code and check generated-sources folder under target

Comment: I'll dig into this, and keep you updated, thanks for the tip, if it works, i'll not forget to accept the answer

Comment: Sure. Just a word of advice. With QueryDsl you  need to compile your code first which woul generate these Q Files and then you need to include generated-sources folder as source directory in your IDE inorder to not get compile time issues. This whole thing is only when you are working in a IDE. but when you deploy and run, this shouldn't be a problem